# Proof that there exists $K \trianglelefteq H $ such that $K$ and $H/K$ are abelian (under certain conditions)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, quotient-spaces

I need some hints to solve the following problem in the context of quotient groups and isomorphism theorems:

> Let $N \trianglelefteq G$ with $N$ and $G/N$ abelian groups. Let $H \le G$ be any subgroup of $G$. Proof that there exists $K \trianglelefteq H $ such that $K$ and $H/K$ are abelian groups.

Comment: "Let $H\leq H$" should be...?

Comment: just edited it, thank you

Comment: Couldn't you take $H = G$ ?

Comment: I edited it to make clear that H can be any subgroup of G, it is not fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: consider $K=H \cap N$ and apply the second isomorphism theorem.